# How can I search Google Knowledge Graph for entries with a specific property?

Tags: api, search, google-knowledge-graph

How should one formulate a search query for `kgsearch.googleapis.com` to find all entries in a given category? For example, if I wanted to search for things in the Schema.org category [applicationCategory](http://schema.org/applicationCategory), how would I do it? Something like the following,

```
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=c&types=applicationCategory&key=MYKEYHERE
```

results in an error ("Request contains an invalid argument").  Something like the following,

```
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=c&types=Thing&key=MYKEYHERE
```

is not specific enough, and returns unrelated results.