# How to get Company info from Google?

Tags: google-api

if we search website of the company in google we get following result. i need to get company info and founded year. and no of employee how can i get. is there any API availabe?. can you help me on this. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for the [Google knowledge graph API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph). The info on the box to the right is pulled from the Google Knowledge Graph for the top result.

You can get the information you need for an [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) entity:

> An organization such as a school, NGO, corporation, club, etc.

Example properties of an `Organization` include `legalName`, `logo`, `foundingDate`

For example, here is a simple query I used for Facebook:

```
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=Facebook&key=<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>&indent=True
```

And here is the result I got in return:

```
{
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/m/0hmyfsv",
        "name": "Facebook, Inc.",
        "@type": [
          "Corporation",
          "Organization",
          "Thing"
        ],
        "description": "Social network company",
        "image": {
          "contentUrl": "http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjO7_7_DBuI3EpMBdVTACYT2WDkwKGrBic0JYSGtIt1c_0oMK9",
          "url": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:F_icon.svg"
        },
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
      },
      "resultScore": 32.638672
    }
```

BTW, for some reason, Facebook was the second on the list of results after Youtube

**Update**

Looks like, at the moment, the API does not provide a way to control which properties to be returned in the results, and not all properties are included in the response by default. There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326188/how-can-i-search-google-knowledge-graph-for-entries-with-a-specific-property) about how to get that done

From the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/), the accepted request paramaters are:

- `query` (e.g. `query=Facebook`)
- `ids` (e.g. `ids=/m/0hmyfsv`)
- `languages` (e.g. `languages=en`)
- `types` (e.g. `types=Corporation`)
- `indent` (e.g. `indent=true`)
- `limit` (e.g. `limit=2`)

And the response parameters are: `@id`, `name`,`@type`, `description`, `image` `detailedDescription` (if available), and `resultScore`

The information you are looking for are actually available in the Wikipedia page included in the URL provided as part of the `detailedDescription` property, so you may want to consider using the **[Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php)** instead

Comment: https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=Facebook&key=<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>&indent=True  this not retuning exact result which i expected. Logo[ok], url[ok] but i could not able to get founded & no of employee.

Answer (score 2):

Run following query in [wikidata sparql endpoint](https://query.wikidata.org/)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
?wdindustryLabel 
?wdcompanyName 
?wdcountryLabel 
(SAMPLE(?wdemployee) AS ?wdemployee) 
(SAMPLE(?wdfounded) AS ?wdfounded) 
(SAMPLE(?wdofficial_website) AS ?wdofficial_website) 
WHERE {
  ?wdcompany wdt:P31 ?type;
    rdfs:label ?wdcompanyName.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?wdcompany wdt:P452 ?wdindustry;
      wdt:P1128 ?wdemployee;
      wdt:P571 ?wdfounded;
      wdt:P17 ?wdcountry;
      wdt:P856 ?wdofficial_website.
  }
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?wdcompanyName), "EN"))
  VALUES ?type {
    wd:Q6881511
    wd:Q43229
  }
  VALUES ?wdcompanyName {
    "Apple Inc."@en
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?wdcompanyName ?wdindustryLabel ?wdcountryLabel
ORDER BY (?wdcompanyName)
```

[image]

or use following code:

```
# pip install sparqlwrapper
# https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/

import sys
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

endpoint_url = "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql"

query = """SELECT DISTINCT ?wdindustryLabel ?wdcompanyName ?wdcountryLabel (SAMPLE(?wdemployee) AS ?wdemployee) (SAMPLE(?wdfounded) AS ?wdfounded) (SAMPLE(?wdofficial_website) AS ?wdofficial_website) WHERE {
  ?wdcompany wdt:P31 ?type;
    rdfs:label ?wdcompanyName.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?wdcompany wdt:P452 ?wdindustry;
      wdt:P1128 ?wdemployee;
      wdt:P571 ?wdfounded;
      wdt:P17 ?wdcountry;
      wdt:P856 ?wdofficial_website.
  }
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?wdcompanyName), "EN"))
  VALUES ?type {
    wd:Q6881511
    wd:Q43229
  }
  VALUES ?wdcompanyName {
    'Apple Inc.'@en
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?wdcompanyName ?wdindustryLabel ?wdcountryLabel
Order By ?wdcompanyName"""


def get_results(endpoint_url, query):
    user_agent = "WDQS-example Python/%s.%s" % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1])
    # TODO adjust user agent; see https://w.wiki/CX6
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper(endpoint_url, agent=user_agent)
    sparql.setQuery(query)
    sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
    return sparql.query().convert()


results = get_results(endpoint_url, query)

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    print(result)
```